# kubuntu 12.04 runs slowly

Tags: nvidia, 64-bit, kubuntu, ati

i have a 3ghz amd 64 dual core am3 socket processor, asus mom board, 4GB ram, 8800GTS nividia video card with 500MB ram.

installed kubuntu 12.04 and very laggy.  select menu and 20 seconds later the menu pops up.  i switched to classic menu and that seemed to help.  what direction should i look first to get this running better? video perhaps? i had ubuntu 11.04 on this machine previously and had no problems with speed.

Answer (score 1):

Run the Hardware Drivers program to check for propriatary graphics drivers, these run much faster than the open-source one's that are running on install...

Comment: Just to specify, you need the `nvidia-current` driver.